# How to add space between items on MasterDetail Page?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I wonder to know how to make the item separate, rather than very close to each other. Right now, each item is too close on iOS. 
I try to set Margin and Space both on the ListView and StackLayout, but space between each item didn't change. In order to add space, I figure out that I need to do something with image cell. Image cell is inherited from text cell, but there is no property set a margin or space. Does anyone know how to do the trick?

```
public MasterPageCS ()
{
    var masterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem> ();
    masterPageItems.Add (new MasterPageItem {
        Title = "Contacts",
        IconSource = "contacts.png",
        TargetType = typeof(ContactsPageCS)
    });
    masterPageItems.Add (new MasterPageItem {
        Title = "TodoList",
        IconSource = "todo.png",
        TargetType = typeof(TodoListPageCS)
    });
    masterPageItems.Add (new MasterPageItem {
        Title = "Reminders",
        IconSource = "reminders.png",
        TargetType = typeof(ReminderPageCS)
    });

    listView = new ListView {
        ItemsSource = masterPageItems,
        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (() => {
            var imageCell = new ImageCell ();   //This one!!!!
            imageCell.SetBinding (TextCell.TextProperty, "Title");
            imageCell.SetBinding (ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, "IconSource");
            return imageCell;
        }),
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None
    };

    Padding = new Thickness (0, 40, 0, 0);
    Icon = "hamburger.png";
    Title = "Personal Organiser";
    Content = new StackLayout {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Children = {
            listView
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is someone ask similar question: [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88282/how-to-add-space-between-items-on-masterdetail-page#latest)

Use ViewCell, that way you can control the layout and spacing, the built in layout templates are only useful for basic stuff.

There's a sample here on using ViewCell.

[Adding padding inside ViewCell xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674995/adding-padding-inside-viewcell-xamarin)

My suggestion would be to use Grid's for custom layouts where possible, better performance and less hassles cross platform, stacklayouts can cause issues in iOS in datatemplates especially the height is Auto.

If you use TextCell & ImageCell then Forms takes a best guess to help you.

Also if you use a Grid for your MasterPageItem children, Set the RowSpacing to 0 in the Grid, only then will the margins you set in the data template start to work as you expect.